# Should I replace (void*, size) with a GSL span?

Tags: c++, guideline-support-library

Suppose I have

```
int foo(void* p, size_t size_in_bytes);
```

and assume it doesn't make sense to make `foo` typed. I want to be a good coder and apply the C++ core guidelines. Specifically, I want to use spans instead of (*, len) pairs. Well, `span<void>` won't compile (can't add to a `void *`); and `span<char>` or `span<uint8_t>` etc. would imply foo actually expects chars, which it might not.

So should I use a `span<something-with-size-1>` in this case, or stick with `void*`?

Comment: Make the function template with correct type ?

Comment: `template<typename T> int foo(T&&)` that would do.

Comment: @Jarod42: You're assuming there is a correct type. What if the function checks whether the buffer intersects a region in my memory space which is, say, mapped to a file?

Comment: What? `span` looks like the GSL generalized version of `string_view`, which is not applicable to this situation at all.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Why the forwarding reference? OP simply wants a pointer and a size, or some C++ thing that could represent that, but `T&&` could literally be anything (rvalue reference, lvalue reference, pointer, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I chose to do, and what I think is, shall we say, sound design-wise, is implement a class named `memory_region`, which has all of the type-inspecific functionality of `gsl::span` (hence, for example, it doesn't have a begin() or an end()). It is *not* the same thing as a span of bytes, IMO - and I can structurally never get them mixed up.

Here's my [implementation](https://gist.github.com/eyalroz/faa004ff5b03371a52e71d0f7f88bfc2) (it's part of a repository of DBMS-related GPU kernels and a testing framework I'm working on, hence the CUDA-related snippet; and it depends on some GSL, in my case gsl-lite by MS'es should be ok too I think).

Answer (score 5):

There can be no general answer to this question.

For a function to say that it takes a `span<T>` means that it takes a contiguous array of values, without any form of ownership transference. If that description does not reasonably represent what is going on, then it should not take a `span<T>`.

For example:

> What if the function checks whether the buffer intersects a region in my memory space which is, say, mapped to a file?

That doesn't sound like a `span<T>`. That sounds like you should have a simple aggregate with a name that makes it clear what it means:

```
struct memory_region
{
  void* p;
  size_t size_in_bytes;
};
```

You could even give it a member function for testing intersections. If you are making a system for dealing with such regions of memory, I might advise a more encapsulated class type with constructors and such.

What type the function takes should explain what the data means. Preferably this meaning would be in a general sense, but at the very least, it should say what it means for the function in question.

---

One more thing:

> or `span<uint8_t>` etc. would imply foo actually expects chars

No, it would not. While `uint8_t` will almost certainly have the same size as an `unsigned char`, that does not mean that one would expect to be able to pass an array of characters to any function which takes `span<uint8_t>`. If that function wanted to advertise that it accepted characters, it would have used `unsigned char`.

---

> I meant to say `span<whatever>` would imply the function expect `whatever`'s.

Yes, the requirement for `span`s is that it is passed an actual array of `T`s of the given size.

Answer (score 1):

The proposal before the C++ standardization committee is that if you want to pass around a pointer to a sequence of bytes (which is often what people want to do when passing `void*` around), then you would pass a `span<std::byte>`, which relies upon a new `std::byte` type. However, that requires a small change to the language standard to be legal.

In today's C++, you could pass `span<unsigned char>` (typedef'd as you find most descriptive) and get the same effect: access to a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Can you possibly  link to that proposal?

Comment: Ping on my earlier comment.